# apply recipe to all the servers whose hostnames matches regexp using CHEF

Tags: ruby, linux, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I'm creating a chef recipe to apply a configuration change on all servers whose hostname matches a specific pattern using regexp. However, I'm not sure how to do it.

Example: my hostname looks like this:

- dvabwichf01
- dvcdwichf01

my recipe in default.rb is :

```
case node['hostname']
when '*ab*'
  template "/tmp/regextest" do
    source "test_ab.erb"
    mode "0644"
  end
else
  template "/tmp/regextest" do
    source "test_cd.erb"
    mode "0644"
  end
end
```

But this is not working as expected, only the "else" template is updating on all servers. please assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use an actual regex, not a string like you have there (also you're using fnmatch glob matching, not a regex). That would only fix when the hostname is literally `*ab*`. A regexp literal in Ruby usually looks like `/whatever/`. so `when /ab/` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I used switch for choosing values by adding a method in my helper file (in my case I put it into / app / helpers / application_helper.rb
Example below:
    def name_of_your_method(hostname)
    case hostname
      when "Host1"
        "template_1"
      when "Host2"
        "template_2"
      when "Host2"
        "template_3"
      when "Host3"
        "template_4"
      else 
        "template_default"
    end
  end

Then in your code you would use the name in your method:

```
<%= user.hostname %>
```

And in your table(data)  you would have a column for hostname(in this example)

Hope this helps